# DocuSIgn - SOAP API - How to Force Envelope Assignment

Tags: soap, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign [SOAP API](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/APIGuide.htm) for e-signature. One of the step requires witness. The way I have it set up is to after the recipient 1 signs the envelope, they get it again at which point they are required to assign to another person for witness. But some recipients do not read the instructions and themselves sign as witness. I am not using template.

Is there a way to force them to assign at this step? The witness is generally their manager and hence known.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using InPerson Signing recipient for your witness scenario. It requires that you include a "Host Signer" that will conduct the In person Signing. You can find more details at https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00003931.

Comment: In person signing is not allowed, as it defeats the purpose of the whole process.